# Visual Studio Code will not recognize any JDKs

Tags: java, macos, visual-studio-code

I am fairly new at this so please be patient as I will not always know what you are talking about and may not know what information is helpful to provide. I am trying to set up VSCode as my IDE for java on my macOS Monterey 12.3.1 device. I have the Java Extension Pack that Microsoft recommends.

Anytime I open a .java file, I get an error notification saying "The java.jdt.ls.java.home variable defined in Visual Studio Code settings does not point to a JDK. Source: Language Support for Java by Red Hat."

The variable it is talking about, I copied the path directly from the jdk folder that is returned when I run "java -version" through the terminal. Any other jdk version I have tried, it also does not recognize. Even when I go through VSCode and click "locate an existing jdk" and point it to the location, it tells me the folder I've selected is not a jdk.

I have deleted and reinstalled all of my jdks as well as VSC several times. I even tried downloading the package of VSC, a JDK, and the java extensions that Microsoft put together. I do not know what else to do.

I have seen some online forums talking about the environment variable JAVA_HOME, but I am having trouble grasping the concept or understanding what I can do with that information.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions or if you need me to provide more information. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the `java.jdt.ls.java.home` you configured in **settings.json**?

Comment: "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk",

Comment: Update: I am now using Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Follow this [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial/) to get started with Java in VS Code.

By default, Java programs can run normally without setting `java.jdt.ls.java.home`.

[image]

If you need to specify the JDK, you can use the following configuration in the **settings.json**

```json
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-8.0.332.9-hotspot",
            "default" : true,
        },
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-17",
            "path": "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-17.0.3.7-hotspot",
        },
    ],
```

*It can also be selected in the **JAVA PROJECTS** panel*

[image]

You can also use `java.jdt.ls.java.home` to specify the folder path to the JDK (17 or more recent) used to launch the Java Language Server.

```json
    "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "c:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-17.0.3.7-hotspot",
```

***The above paths are the folders where Java is installed, not `Java.exe`.***

#### About JAVA_HOME

This is an environment variable set for your system so that Java commands are available anywhere on your machine.

*Take **windows** as an example (sorry I don't have a **mac**)*

- Add `JAVA_HOME` to system environment variables

  [image]
- Then add the java path to path

  [image]

*The effect is equivalent to adding the Java `bin` path directly to the **Path***

Comment: Where is this `settings.json` of which you speak?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson